# C# Deserialize JSON list WinForm Combobox

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I am trying to build an application that is reading a json file, converts it to c# objects and prints the output based on user's selected item from a combobox.

The JSON file looks like this

```
[
{
    "Description": "Some text here.",
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Option 1",
},
{
    "Description": "Another different text here",
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Option 2",

}
```

]

The class is defined like this:

```
    public class Incident
{

    public Incident()
    {
    }
    public Incident(int id, string name, string description)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I am filling the combobox with the values from the name field like so:

```
            var jsonPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Data", "configuration.json");
            // Read values from file
            var strReadJson = File.ReadAllText(jsonPath);
            // Convert to Json Object
            var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Incident>>(strReadJson);

            foreach (var option in x.Select(p => p.Name))
            {
                boxOptions.Items.Add(option);
                boxOptions.Sorted = true;
            }
```

Now I would like to populate a textbox with the incident's description field based on the selected name from combobox, I this is the part where I got stucked.

So, if the user selects from combobox the name "Option 1", the textbox should display "Some text here", if "Option 2" is selected then "Another different text" should be displayed.

I don't know if ***foreach*** loop should be applied here since it will display all descriptions field from the list.

I appreciate any help provided.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to do the same from client side or server side ?

Comment: did u implement your `SelectedIndexChanged` for combobox?

Comment: @Arunprasanth K V There is no client/server side.

Comment: Ok then write a method which accepts the selected option value and query your list based on the value and get the FirstOrDefault() from the list and send it back to the requester.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check

Private Variable
`List<Incident> x = new List<Incident>();`

Read File (used your code)

```
    private void frmSampleJson_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Json = File.ReadAllText(@"d://read.txt").ToString();
        //Read the Array
        JArray array = JArray.Parse(Json);
        //Sort the Array
        JArray sorted = new JArray(array.OrderBy(obj => (string)obj["Name"]));
        //Added sorted JArray to List<Incident>
        x = sorted.ToObject<List<Incident>>();

        foreach (var option in x.Select(p => p.Name))
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(option);                
        }
    }
```

Now on Combox Properties Used `SelectedIndexChange` Event

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int nIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        string strDesc = x[nIndex].Description;
        textBox1.Text = strDesc;
    }
```

[image: On Selecting Combo Box Item 1]

[image: On Selecting Combo Box Item 2]

Comment: Thanks for this solution, seems to be working without comboBox1.Sorted. Somehow adding comboBox1.Sorted = true changes the selectedindex of the combobox and fills the textbox with a wrong value. I need to investigate this further and find a way to sort the combobox alphabetically without an impact on the textbox.

Comment: @MihaiDumitru Check adding `comboBox1.Sorted = true;` before `foreach` loop

Comment: Try to use this json string having **comboBox1.Sorted = true;**:
`[
{
    "Description": "Option 1",
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Option 1"
},
{
    "Description": "Option 2",
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Option 2"
},
 {
  "Description": "Varianta 3",
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "Varianta 3"
 },
{
    "Description": "Option 4",
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Option 4"
},
{
    "Description": "Option 5",
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Option 5"
}
]`

You will see that **Varianta 3** will be added as last option in the combobox but when you select it the textbox will display `Option 5`.

Comment: @MihaiDumitru have edited my answer. Please Check. Sorted the Json Array before adding to the `List<Incident>()` so you can remove `comboBox1.Sorted = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Use ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged event. In the event fill the textbox with the value from Combobox. Refer the code below:

```
// Add this in the Form Initialization or Form_Load()
boxOptions.SelectedIndexChanged += new 
 system.EventHandler(boxOptions_SelectedIndexChanged);

// Event Handler
private void boxOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    txtBox1.Text = comboBox_Code1.Text;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this solution only copies the selected text from the combobox to the textbox, I am looking for logic to match the selected combobox item with its description and put the description in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert the `json` object into C# list.

Then simply place a where condition to match with your condition and return that object to the `UI`.

```
    public class YourModel
      {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
      }

    class YourClass
      {
        public IEnumerable<YourModel> YourModels{ get; set; }
      }

 string jsonString = //your json will go here

                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                YourClass data= serializer.Deserialize<YourClass >(jsonString);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks you, but exactly that condition you are talking about I do not know how to do it.

Comment: which one the where condition part ?